# Assembly mov from memory to memory with push

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, stack

I have a double word in the data section called pos.
If I execute `push dword [pos]` it will store the value of pos on the stack. But if I replace it with `sub esp, 4; mov [esp], dword [pos]` it won't work anymore. Why is push able to move a value from memory to memory and mov isn't?

Comment: You can only encode one memory operand in the instruction format. And for push that's enough.

Comment: Because there is only place for one memory operand in the machine code. So at least one operand must be implicit. In case of `push` that's of course the `[esp]`. Also note there is the string move, `movsd` and friends, where both operands are implicit and those can also do memory to memory copy (it's their explicit purpose).